# problemas al crear un proyecto de gitlab

Tags: git

teníamos un proyecto en un repositorio y resulta que lo mudaron, así que hice hit clone desde el mismo directorio donde tenia el proyecto anterior. pero cuándo hago git branch -a no me muestra las ramas, y si hago git remote -v no aparece el repositorio. que hice mal? se me ocurrió ejecutar git init desde ese directorio y la cosa como que está peor. la verdad que por más que he leído como funciona git estoy bastante confundido, ahora no se como hacer para conectarme a ese nuevo repositorio.

Comment: tenes que hacer git clone a una carpeta nueva en teoria.. si no como que estaria mezclando las cosas.. o mucho mejor, actualizar las referencias de tu carpeta anterior al nuevo proyecto (pero por como funciona git, borrar y clone suena mejor)

Comment: como podria hacer para hacer todo desde cero, porque ahora hice git init desde ese directorio, pero si hago git remote -v no aparece nada, ni el anterior ni el nuevo.

Comment: renombra esa carpeta.. olvidate que existe.. crea una nueva.. y hace clone ahi... y fijate si desde ahi anda todo bien...

Comment: Ya lo logré descargar. yo tengo esta una carpeta llamada _rss en el servidor local, dentro de esta carpeta deberían estar todos los archivos de la aplicación, pero cuando bajo el repositorio este me viene en una carpeta llamada competition y dentro de esta carpeta es donde estan los archivos que deberían estar directamente dentro de la carpeta _rss , si ejecuto git remote -v dentro de _rss no funciona, el comando funciona es dentro de la carpeta competition, como haría para mover todos los archivos de la carpeta competition a la carpeta _rss y que el repositorio este en _rss ?

Comment: debo mover la carpeta .git a la carpeta _rss ?

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero, busca un buen tutorial de git, y apréndelo bien, te va a hacer falta :)

Una solución sin muchas complicaciones es, si no quieres perder posibles cambios locales, crea otra carpeta en tu local, y descárgate el repositorio con git clone. Luego copias ahí el contenido nuevo desde tu carpeta anterior.

Si no tienes nada nuevo hecho en local, simplemente borra tu local, y descárgalo de nuevo. Acabarás antes :)

Comment: si hago un ls -a aparece la carpeta .git , esa debo eliminarla ?

Comment: Sí, elimina por completo tu carpeta local. Luego la creas de nuevo, y tal cual, vacía, ejecutas ahí git clone http://github....  Con eso tendrás el repositorio como nuevo en local, con los cambios que estén en remoto

Comment: Es la forma bruta pero efectiva, algo similar es borrar la carpeta del repositorio `.git` y volver a inicializar con la nueva ruta `git init`, `git remote add origin  https://gitlab.com/usuario/nuevo_repositorio`. O mucho mejor `git remote set-url origin https://gitlab.com/usuario/nuevo_repositorio`

Comment: mi internet está funcionando extremadamente lento, si lo clono con git clone 'enlace git' depth 1 , cuál seria la diferencia o en que me afectaría ?

Comment: probé con eso hace días y era la única forma con la que se me lograba descargar.

Comment: Ya lo logré descargar. yo tengo esta una carpeta llamada _rss en el servidor local, dentro de esta carpeta deberían estar todos los archivos de la aplicación, pero cuando bajo el repositorio este me viene en una carpeta llamada competition y dentro de esta carpeta es donde estan los archivos que deberían estar directamente dentro de la carpeta _rss , si ejecuto git remote -v dentro de _rss no funciona, el comando funciona es dentro de la carpeta competition, como haría para mover todos los archivos de la carpeta competition a la carpeta _rss y que el repositorio este en _rss ?

Comment: debo mover la carpeta .git a la carpeta _rss ?

Comment: Borra la carpeta rss de tu local. En ese nivel, haz git clone [direccion url] _rss, y eso te creará el repositorio tal y como está en la nube, pero dentro de una carpeta llamada _rss. Eso debería funcionarte